# What if the same amount of mass equaled double the amount of weight? Why is the force of 1N what it is?

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity, mass, acceleration, universe

Assume gravity's acceleration stayed the same (9.8 m/s²) but pretend if you take the same amount of mass and the actual force is double.  So if you weighed 200#, now you weigh 400#. Lets pretend that this was the amount of weight from day 1 for the entire universe, this would then mean that all mass would apply double the force at any acceleration in order to satisfy the ratios of acceleration x mass.  So here is my actual question.  Why is the "actual" force to accelerate matter what it is?  Why not double the force, tripple the force or even half the force to what we are use to. I understand that this would mean that the force of matter would double, tripple or half at any mass and acceleration in order to satisfy newtons law of force.  Is this just something we "Accept" as a standard that 1N of force is .224 pounds (.1020kg force)  I understand how we get .224 pounds to 1 N because force to accelerate 0.1020 kg mass at 9.8 m/s²= 1 N and .1020 kg mass at 9.8 m/s²puts out .1020 kg force since its mass to force ratio 1:1 ratio at 9.8 m/s² for kg mass to kg force then its just a matter of converting kg force to pounds force.  Like I said mass x acceleration = N basically just says whatever amount of force it takes to accelerate 1 kg of matter at 1 m/s² = 1 N of force.  Why is this "whatever amount" what it is and not more or less.  Is it just accepted.  Sorry if I might have asked the same question twice.

Comment: Your text is not easy to get through. Would you mind breaking it into more eatable chunks?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be asking about gravitational mass and inertial mass, and mixing your units. Let's clear a few things up:

"Gravitational mass" is the property of matter that causes an attractive force between two objects. The magnitude of the force is given by

$$F = \frac{G M_1 M_2}{r^2}$$

Where $G$ is the gravitational constant, $6.67\cdot 10^{-11} N m^2 / kg^2$.

The "inertial mass" is the property that causes an object to resist a change in its velocity, according to

$$F = ma$$

Now it is found, through many careful experiments, that an object with a certain inertial mass always has a corresponding gravitational mass. The actual scale factor that relates the two kinds of mass is the gravitational constant.

It seems to me you are asking "if the gravitational constant had a different value, would we know?". I believe the answer is "no" - but there may be others here who have a deeper understanding of these things.